# Sidekiq error on required ruby file

Tags: ruby, sidekiq, foreman

I'm trying to start my application. Is a unicorn + foreman + sinatra application.

This is my config.ru file:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"

Bundler.require

require File.expand_path '../twitter_module.rb', __FILE__
run TwitterModule

require File.expand_path '../lib/tweet_streamer.rb', __FILE__

require 'sidekiq/web'
run Rack::URLMap.new('/' => Sinatra::Application, '/sidekiq' => Sidekiq::Web)
```

this is my sidekiq.yml:

```
---
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
development:
  :verbose: true
  :logfile: log/sidekiq_development.log
```

and this is my Procfile:

```
unicorn: bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development -r lib/workers
```

The problem now is that I always give this error:

```
2013-10-12T15:30:23Z 28234 TID-ov4rh38wo INFO:   Please point sidekiq to a Rails 3/4 application or a Ruby file  
2013-10-12T15:30:23Z 28234 TID-ov4rh38wo INFO:   to load your worker classes with -r [DIR|FILE].
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of specifying the `lib/workers/` directory as the `-r` option for sidekiq, it's necessary to point it to some file which will deal with the necessary requires and setup for your workers. For example, you might have an `environment.rb` file in the root of your project, requiring all the workers within the `lib/workers/` directory; you'd specify this with Sidekiq by using `-r ./environment.rb`. It might perhaps be useful to note that Sidekiq won't load your `config.ru` file by itself as it doesn't use Rackup; instead, you might like to extract anything necessary to an `environment.rb` file or similar, and require that from within `config.ru`.

Comment: Thanks I solve this problem. Is just that you have to point it to a ruby file that require 'sidekiq'. Now I have a different problem, I have all the jobs stucked on queued, they are not being processed and I can't understand why. Sidekiq is running and also redis is up. Any idea?

Comment: @user1197854, Yes, it would also be necessary to require sidekiq in the environment.rb (or similar) file I mentioned. For stuck queues, some good things to check are: Sidekiq connection to Redis (is it the right one?) with server/client blocks; Redis namespace (if you're using one); queue types (default, etc.); required workers; errors in workers or processing. (p.s. If my environment.rb post above answered your question, don't forget to 'accept' it. :) )

Comment: sure thanks you. Redis is up on the 6379 default port, and because of that I don't have a server/client blocks. I don't have namespace (should I?). The queue is default. The worker for now is just a print in the log file.

Comment: It's not necessary to use a namespace (although it can be good practice—but that is unlikely to be the cause of the troubles you're experiencing). I'm afraid there's not enough information; I suggest you make a new question, with details of: the command you're using to run sidekiq workers; any configuration; a possibly-edited version of your worker code. Hopefully, we'll be able to help, then. :) Feel free to put a link to the new issue in a comment here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364978/sidekiq-does-not-process-jobs-jobs-stuck-in-enqueue I posted all my code here :)