# sidekiq does not process jobs, jobs stuck in enqueue

Tags: ruby, redis, unicorn, sidekiq

I have a simple application that works with the twitter stream api, sidekiq, unicorn and sinatra. All works well, instead of... the job are not being processed at all. They are stuck in Enqueued (And I know that from the sidekiq web UI).

This is my code:

Procfile:

```
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development -r ./lib/tweet_streamer.rb
unicorn: bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
redis: redis-stable/src/redis-server
```

config/unicorn.rb:

```
listen 5000, :tcp_nopush => true
timeout 30
preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

before_fork do |server, worker|
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
end
```

the tweet_streamer.rb:

```
require_relative "../config/tweetstream"
require_relative "workers"

class TweetStreamer

  client = TweetStream::Client.new
  client.on_enhance_your_calm do |s|
    puts "on_enhance_your_calm #{s}"
  end

  puts "onstream"

  client.userstream do |status|
    ##
    ## TODO: Some kind of log
    ##
    puts "start process"
    # TweetStatusWorker.perform_async(status.to_hash)
    Sidekiq::Client.push('class' => TweetStatusWorker, 'args' => ["a"])
    puts "process started!"
  end

end
```

the workers.rb

```
require_relative "../config/sidekiq"
require_relative 'workers/tweet_status_worker'
```

the config/sidekiq.rb:

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 1 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 6 }
end
```

the worker:

```
class TweetStatusWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(status)
    logger.warn "I'm working on it!"
  end
end
```

My sidekiq.yml:

```
 ---
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
development:
  :verbose: true
  :logfile: log/sidekiq_development.log
```

My config.ru:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"

Bundler.require

require File.expand_path '../twitter_module.rb', __FILE__

require 'sidekiq/web'

run Rack::URLMap.new('/' => TwitterModule, '/sidekiq' => Sidekiq::Web)
```

My app class:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class TwitterModule < Sinatra::Base
end
```

This is the log that I received when I start the application and I make a tweet for start a process and all seems to be fine..

````
17:36:31 sidekiq.1 | started with pid 65599
17:36:31 unicorn.1 | started with pid 65600
17:36:31 redis.1   | started with pid 65601
17:36:31 redis.1   | [65601] 14 Oct 17:36:31.717 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-stable/src/redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
17:36:31 redis.1   | [65601] 14 Oct 17:36:31.718 * Max number of open files set to 10032
17:36:31 redis.1   |                 _._                                                  
17:36:31 redis.1   |            _.-``__ ''-._                                             
17:36:31 redis.1   |       _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 2.6.16 (f132ada8/1) 64 bit
17:36:31 redis.1   |   .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
17:36:31 redis.1   |  (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in stand alone mode
17:36:31 redis.1   |  |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
17:36:31 redis.1   |  |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 65601
17:36:31 redis.1   |   `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
17:36:31 redis.1   |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
17:36:31 redis.1   |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
17:36:31 redis.1   |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
17:36:31 redis.1   |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
17:36:31 redis.1   |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
17:36:31 redis.1   |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
17:36:31 redis.1   |       `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
17:36:31 redis.1   |           `-._        _.-'                                           
17:36:31 redis.1   |               `-.__.-'                                               
17:36:31 redis.1   | 
17:36:31 redis.1   | [65601] 14 Oct 17:36:31.719 # Server started, Redis version 2.6.16
17:36:31 redis.1   | [65601] 14 Oct 17:36:31.728 * DB loaded from disk: 0.010 seconds
17:36:31 redis.1   | [65601] 14 Oct 17:36:31.728 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
17:36:33 unicorn.1 | I, [2013-10-14T17:36:33.208428 #65600]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
17:36:33 unicorn.1 | I, [2013-10-14T17:36:33.813454 #65600]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:5000 fd=9
17:36:33 unicorn.1 | I, [2013-10-14T17:36:33.814790 #65600]  INFO -- : master process ready
17:36:33 unicorn.1 | I, [2013-10-14T17:36:33.816138 #65607]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
17:36:33 sidekiq.1 | onstream
17:36:43 sidekiq.1 | start process
17:36:43 sidekiq.1 | process started!
````

nothing in the sidekiq log obviously:

```
2013-10-14T16:36:43Z 65599 TID-ouo5je95k INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.15.1 using redis://localhost:6379/0 with options {:size=>6}
2013-10-14T16:37:32Z 65599 TID-ouo5je95k DEBUG: Terminating 4 actors...
```

UPDATE:

Ok I found it. Is the streamer the problem. If I run the job outside of the streamer block, this works well. Any Idea about why this append and how I can solve it?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't been able to spot what's wrong; I created a small application with most parts from your files, but it's working for me. Do you have a `config/sidekiq.rb`? I see a require in your code (different to `config/sidekiq.yml`). What happens when you command-line `bundle exec irb` then `require 'sidekiq'; require './lib/workers/tweet_status_worker'; TweetStatusWorker.perform_async('a')` or similar? Does an id like '2ea460d8742ec6b26c3816a3' get returned? Is new job visible added in Sidekiq Web? Does Sidekiq process the job?

Comment: I added the config/sidekiq.rb content to my question. I tryed what you write above, and yes, it return the id, but nothing append, nothing move on the sidekiq log or on the redis server and for the sidekiq web how can I start it from command line? Doing just via irb doesn't start sidekiq isn't? 
irb(main):001:0> require 'sidekiq'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require './lib/workers/tweet_status_worker'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> TweetStatusWorker.perform_async('a')
2013-10-14T22:52:29Z 2024 TID-ouy95m574 INFO: Sidekiq client using redis://localhost:6379/0 with options {}
=> "fc2db03ac35ac127d1317dca"

Comment: Ok I found it. Is the streamer the problem. If I run the job outside of the streamer block, this works well. Any Idea about why this append and how I can solve it?

Comment: Interesting! I suspect you're getting caught out by TweetStream being evented; perhaps you don't actually have a connection within that block. I suggest you read the section following 'A frequent use case is to use TweetStream along with ActiveRecord to insert new statuses to a database.' in the TweetStream README; you might have to reestablish the connection after it forks, just like for when using a database connection. Maybe try comparing debug lines inside and outside that block using `Sidekiq.redis { |c| c.client }`.

Comment: Sidekiq.redis { |c| c.client } just print the same text. I also tried to ping redis inside and outside, and it's ok. So, can be the connection between sidekiq & redis? And in that case, do you know how I can reconnect sidekiq with redis?

Comment: I found it. Is because I'm starting sidekiq with actually the streamer. Just start them as separate process from the Procfile solve the problem! Thanks for the help anyway! Maybe this can be useful for someone else.