# Progressive migration from delayed_job to Sidekiq wents messy by require Ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, sidekiq

I'm trying to migrate from Delayed_Job to Sidekiq. and by running Sidekiq in kubernetes an unrecognised error comes to surface:

```
==================================================================
  Please point Sidekiq to a Rails application or a Ruby file  
  to load your job classes with -r [DIR|FILE].
==================================================================
```

Kubernetes deployment snippet:

```
      ...
      containers:
        - name: sidekiq
          image: {{ application_registry }}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command:
            - bundle
          args:
            - exec
            - sidekiq
            - -r # not included in the original setting.
            - /app/config/application.rb # not included in the original setting.
            - "-C"
            - "/app/config/sidekiq.yml"
          resources:
            ...
```

PS: A lot of existing jobs still lay on DelayJob, some we plan to progressively migrate. so we include Sidekiq per job not globally:

```
class FirstJob < ApplicationJob
      self.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

      ...
```

Following some guides described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339758/6589296). I tried to require the `config/application.rb` under the `-r` flag, but nothing fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

```
        - -r # not included in the original setting.
        - /app/config/application.rb # not included in the original setting.
        - "-C"
        - "/app/config/sidekiq.yml"
```

You need to set the current working directory to /app.

Comment: Hi, I still blocked in the same error. whatever changes I made had no effect on failed situation. I tried to get rid of this line from the K8t file. and mention the `workingDir` to `/app`. but still failing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this done with mounting a different volume for sidekiq.yml config file.

```yaml
...
command:
  - bundle
args:
  - exec
  - sidekiq
  - "-C"
  - "/config/sidekiq.yml"
...
volumeMounts:
  - name: sidekiq-yml
    mountPath: /config
```